# How to export to *.so file after patching in ghidra

Tags: patching, apk, ghidra, shared-object

I'm using ghidra to patch an *.so file in the Android APK.
While exporting the patched file from ghidra, using the "Export program" option from the "File" menu, it don't have *.so in the supported "Format".

- c/c++ will result in *.c file,
- binary will result in *.bin file.

How can I export to *.so file?

[image]

This might be a very silly question but it would be great if someone could give me any hints.